# GoogleDrive metadata for copied images

Tags: google-drive-api

Im getting images from GoogleDrive via **files.list** method, response looks like this:

```
items:[{
  "title": "canon_eos_30D.CR2",
  "fileExtension": "cr2",
  "imageMediaMetadata": {
    "width": 3504,
    "height": 2336
   }
}]
```

Everything is OK, but after I **copied** this image via GoogleDrive **web interface** response looks like this.

```
items:[{
  "title": "Copy of canon_eos_30D.CR2",
  "fileExtension": "cr2",
  "imageMediaMetadata": {
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0
   }
}]
```

imageMediaMetadata **is not copied!** (doesn't matter what jpg or cr2). Then I tried to copy image on machine and sync it via client — everything is OK.

Looks like imageMediaMetadata parsed during image import and this is GoogleDrive bug.

Is there any way to get this info to workaround this bug or is there any way to force metadata reparsing until this bug is there?

P.S.: JFYI: If I add **properties** field to filter to `files.list` method these broken metadata fields excluded from response.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with how image files are copied in the Drive UI. Copying image files via the Drive API doesn't have this issue. A workaround, if unpleasant one, is to download and re-upload the contents of the file, which will cause it to be re-scanned and the metadata to be populated.

Comment: If you have link to this issue, please add it. I want to track progress.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't maintain a public issue tracker for the Drive API or product.